# Make all help pages work in shorthand links

Tags: feature-request, comments, help-center, short-links

Currently you can write `[help/on-topic]` in a comment, which changes to [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and there's some other similar help short-links (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)).

But not all of them work - `[help/someone-answers]` doesn't change to [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), it just stays that text (and no, I wasn't trying to force accepting an answer down someone's throat, just elaborating on someone else' hopelessly underspecified comment).

Can we change this so all `[help/...]` links changes to
`[help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/...)`?

It should be fairly trivial to change it to the applicable link only if that link exists.

Or is there a reason we don't want to do this?